# Lenovo L430 malfunction brightness control 13.04

Tags: 13.04, brightness, lenovo

I use a Lenovo L430. Unfortunately after updating to 13.04 the brightness control does not work any more. Hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>/<kbd>F9</kbd> the popup appears but it is changing only one step and the brightness remains the same. Hitting once more the control remains in its position.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug report has already been filed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1098216

The latest kernels (3.8.20 and above) should have fixed the issue.

### Workaround

Add to `/etc/default/grub`
in the variable "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT": `acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\"`

e.g:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\""
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: I have tried it, but nothing changed

Comment: Did you reboot the laptop? It works on my T530.

Comment: Yes, after the secound reboot it worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of this answer working on a lot of Lenovos specifically.

Rather than using `acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\"` as stated by LiveWireBT, instead use `acpi_backlight=vendor`. The process of getting this line added to /etc/default/grub is the same as LiveWireBT stated. This seems to work on many different Lenovo models, perhaps yours is one of them.

Comment: After replacing !Windows 2012 with vendor, kernel hangs on pressing Fn+light buttons! Switched back to !windows 2012