# Brightness keys don't work anymore after upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 on Thinkpad L430

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, brightness, thinkpad

I just updated my Ubuntu system from 13.10 to 14.04. After having fixed GRUB which broke on upgrading, I run into certain other problems.

One of them is that the brightness adjustment keys of my L430 (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) don't work anymore.

I already tried these two solutions:
[Lenovo L430 malfunction brightness control 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298655/lenovo-l430-malefunction-brightness-control-13-04)
[Screen brightness with Fn Keys in Ubuntu 11.04](http://ubuntuguide.net/change-screen-brightness-with-fn-key-in-ubuntu-11-0410-10)

Neither worked. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my issue.

[This one worked for me](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/)

Create this config file

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

And add the following contents:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Brightness keys work after reboot

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact issue on my T61p. I tried a bunch of stuff, but I eventually found this post:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217934

Turns out there may be an issue with the graphics card and the BIOS version in some systems. Since this seems to affect Lenovo PC's especially you may want to give it a shot. I updated my BIOS by going to Lenovo's support website and downloading the BIOS update iso. You want to make sure to download the iso and NOT the .exe file, which is meant for Windows. Once I got the iso I burned to a disc using Brasero and then booted it up. Just follow the instructions in the menu and within a minute you should be updated!

I found that not only was brightness fixed, but my graphics seemed to get an overall improvement as well!

Here's the download page for your model, just double check it before downloading:

http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-l-series-laptops/thinkpad-l430/downloads/DS029125

Also I found the following command helpful as it tells you your current BIOS version; open a terminal and type:

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
```

Anyway, I hope this helps! Been driving me crazy for days!